# Using DOCUMENT.OF KEYDOWN event breaking other keydown events

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want a key down event in documnet. so what I am done is like .added a downkey event in document.

```
     self.cacheDom.$document.off('keydown').on('keydown', function (e) { 

   // my function with a scroll trigger if condition is satisfied 
 });
```

beacuse of this code my another `keydown` event is not working. I bind that event like

```
self.cacheDom.$document.off('keydown').on('keydown', function (e) {
// my another function
});
```

if I remove off `keydown` from first event the second function work otherwise it never work. but I can't remove off `keydown` because it making other issue like multiple  trigger  or scroll event after `keydown` is not working.So is there any way to solve this issue .

Comment: off("foo") will remove every event listener attached to that element with that name. It has no clue what one you want to remove, so it removes everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind keydown event handler again after first function complete,  because you have unbinded all keydown event which are attached same for second event handler also.

```
  self.cacheDom.$document.off('keydown').on('keydown',firstHandler);
  self.cacheDom.$document.off('keydown').on('keydown',firstHandler);


   var firstHandler=function(){
     //my function with a scroll trigger if condition is satisfied 
         self.cacheDom.$document.on('keydown',secondhandler)
    }
   var secondHandler=function(){
     // my another function
         self.cacheDom.$document.on('keydown',firstHandler)
    }
```

Please let me inform is working for you are not.

Comment: @ManuPadmanabhan could you show some more code which you are doing. it will help to know your exact case